# Single word to express "all round support"

Tags: single-word-requests, british-english

If somebody helped an author in many topics, how to express this with sincere gratitude?

**SENTENCE**

*It is a genuine pleasure to express my sincere gratitude and appreciations to people supporting me during the studies:*

- *Professor Xin Ho for inspiring positive attitude, **all-round support**, and extensive personal and professional guidance on research, orthopaedics and life in general;*

> support in many topics

> all-round support

> support in numerous issues

Comment: “A” positive attitude. But don’t write it, it sounds terrible.

Comment: Why not just "support"? Unspecified support can mean general support.

Comment: You're better to use some laudatory adjectives rather than look for a single word.

Comment: You would say "my studies" not "the studies" unless you are referring to a group of specific projects or clinicial trials. Also, "appreciation" in the singular.

Answer (score 0):

"Overall support" would be a good synonym.

[Overall, according to Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overall):

> including everything

Another option would be "comprehensive support".

[Comprehensive, according to Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/comprehensive):

> covering completely or broadly

Comment: Hello, Janikole. OP is asking for a synonym for 'all-round support', not 'all-round'.

Comment: On a re-read, the body does confuse the issue. But if OP is merely asking for a synonym for 'all-round', this should be CV-d for lack of research ([Thesaurus.YourDictionary.com](https://thesaurus.yourdictionary.com/all-round))

Comment: *All-round* is not needed. If the support is not specialised, it is merely *support*.

Answer (score 0):

The word **encouragement** would fit. All dictionaries would say something like "giving support and/or confidence".

Comment: Support and encouragement are slightly different. Support can include practical help.

Comment: Depends on how one understands "all-round". Many people use the phrase "all round support" (in this context of thanking an academic mentor) to refer primarily to emotional support and encouragement more than practical assistance, especially when the practical assistance gets its own separate mention.